# how to force instantiation of a template class used with a type alias

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that takes a large number of template parameters.

This is an helper class that is used only on a predefined list of types.
I use a type alias (`using` or `typedef`) so that the user does not get polluted with the template suff.

As the typelist is hardcoded, I would like to force the instantiation of the class T, but as the list is quite long I'd like to force instantiation without repeating all parameters.

How could I do that?

```
template <class... X>
class T {
};

// alias the type so that the user don't get mad with type list
using Z = T<int, bool, char, long
            /* possibly a long list of parameters*/ >;


// this works but needs to repeat all template arguments
template class T<int, bool, char, long>;

// how to force instantiation of T using Z?
```

Comment: Assuming you want to do this because you want to implement the class template in a .cpp file, did you try creating a static instance of `Z` in _T.cpp_ ?

Comment: @paolo yes exactly, and no I did not try a static instance.

Comment: I tried something with the static (actually, the meyer's singleton) but that does not seem to work because only functions called in the constructor/destructor are actually instantiated (which seems eventually expected because this is just the way templates behave).

Comment: Just adding `static const Z z;` or `static const bool instanciate = [] { Z{}; return false; }();` at the end of _T.cpp_ did the trick for me.

Comment: actually, even the proposed solution does not seem to work: https://godbolt.org/z/14xacYhza

Comment: why you want the instantiate?

Comment: that is an implementation detail but as this is an helper class, I want to put a maximum of my code in the cpp file. So forcing the template instantiation in the cpp would make sure the link will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I used a macro...

```
#define MY_TYPE T<int,bool,char,long>

using Z = MY_TYPE;

template class MY_TYPE;
```

I'm still looking for a better solution...