# why template base class is not forced to be instantiated

Tags: c++, templates

I have 2 template classes and one inherit from the other.

```
template <class T>
class X {
    public:
    int get() { return 1; }
};

template <class T>
class B : public X<T> {};

// Force B instantiation would expect X to be forced as well
template class B<int>;

// If I remove next line, no code is emitted for X
template class X<int>
```

When forcing the template instantiation of B, the X is not instantiated as well ( see https://godbolt.org/z/3vvenM8j4)

What is the reason for that?

Note: This is a follow up to [how to force instantiation of a template class used with a type alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72830020/how-to-force-instantiation-of-a-template-class-used-with-a-type-alias)

I would expect the given solution to work but is does not

Comment: Maybe already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3712309/2001017

Comment: I can definitely do `B<int> b; b.get();` in main without explicit instantiation.

Comment: @MarekR, while `T` is often used, `ALL_UPPERCASE` identifiers are often reserved to macros, so I wouldn't recommend its use. Let the standard library inspire you concerning the naming instead.